How to call 999 and other emergency 3 digit numbers via the Microsoft Graph Call API
We have a BOT which can invite a Teams user or a PSTN (E.164) telephone number into a call via the Graph Call API.
When inviting a telephone number it has to be E.164 (as stated in the API spec).
However, how would I call an emergency number such as 999 or 911 or 112 etc
When I attempt this I get an error "Request authorization tenant mismatch"
Presumably some configuration of Teams is necessary in order to get it to accept these numbers?
Suggestions welcome.
